# How to set an absolute path name using SetDirectory?

Tags: files-and-directories

I tried the following:

```
Directory[]
```

> ```
> /Users/John
> ```

```
SetDirectory["Library/Mathematica"]
```

> ```
> /Users/John/Library/Mathematica
> ```

The documentation for `SetDirectory` says:

> For a relative path name, `SetDirectory` sets the directory relative to the current working directory.

So it seems that `SetDirectory` interprets my argument as a relative path name. How can I get `SetDirectory` to interpret my argument as an absolute path name, so that the result is `/Library/Mathematica` instead of `/Users/John/Library/Mathematica`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a *Mathematica* specific question but in Mac OS X absolute paths begin with a `/` character exactly as you give in your desired result, so

```
SetDirectory["/Library/Mathematica"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want Mathematica to interpret it as an absolute path, why don't you pass it one? In Windows:

> SetDirectory["D:\\Library\\Mathematica"]

will set the path to `D:\Library\Mathematica`.

Comment: are the double backslashes really necessary, in Windows?

Comment: @magma - Apparently not, but I saw them in a notebook I got from WRI, and I sticked to it.

Comment: @magma - Yes, otherwise you'd get the "Unknown string escape" error. When you copy paste a file path within a Mathematica string (""), MMA will prompt you to allow it to insert escape--whatever that means--and you should pick "Yes".

Comment: @seism - I tried it with a single backslash, and it also works. No error, no warning, no prompt.

Comment: @stevenvh I have no idea why mine showed the error. I took a screenshot of it: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma1vA.png). Could you help me use single backlash without error?

Comment: @seismatica and stevenvh the point of my comment was to raise awareness on the issue of inputting file names. The documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InsertAFilePath.html says you must use double backslashes, but also offers drag and drop techniques. In http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InputAndConstructFileNamesInTheWolframLanguage.html you can also read about FilenameJoin

Comment: @stevenvh Please see my comment above

Comment: @seism - 'fraid not. I didn't do anything to make it work, I just noticed it does! :-)

Comment: Certain characters have special meaning in expressions.  When one wants to be sure to avoid confusion a \ [backslash] is used to preappend to those characters so that they  won't cause confusion.  For example (from Mangano2010) Run["\"date /T > date.txt\""; FilePrint["date.txt"] uses the \ to "escape out" the " [double quote] character. Since \ works in this way one needs to have two consecutive backslash characters \\ to insure the second one will appear as a single \ say to separate directories on a Windows system.  Whether one or two s needed will depend on the context and use.